# How do I transfer my garageband project to logic pro without the vocals messing up?

Tags: voice, daw, production

I exported a project to logic from garageband and everything lined up PERFECTLY. I got so excited because I recorded this song years ago before I had logic. I thought everything was perfect until I clicked play. All of the vocals had random sounds in them and there was a lot of extra noise and scratchiness in the logic project.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like something might have gone wrong during the export. You might need to manually export the raw audio of the vocal track and import it into Logic. Another option you could try is disabling any inserts (effects) one by one to see if that fixes the issue. Last thing I can think of is that there may be a buffer size issue. Through preferences in Logic you can increase the buffer size, this could solve crackles and pops you hear during playback.